# How to configure cloudflare with vercel

Tags: cloudflare

Let me try to explain my situation. I am starting studying how to proper configure cloudflare.

I am form Brazil and i have bought my domain (vaquinhaanimal.com.br) on Registro.br that is a brazilian service and the DNS is configurated to point to Vercel that is where my frontend in hosted.

My MX, TXT, CNAME, A.. registers are configurated on Vercel, not on Registro.br.

When configuring cloudflare, they request me to change my dns to point to cloudflare servers but i dont know how to do this. Because if i change it on Registro.br my domain will not more point to my frontend and i think it is not correct. But i don't know if i need to insert this dns on Vercel, i am a little bit lost in this process.

Explaining more:

. Domain register (registro.br) --> DNS pointing to Vercel app (where my frontend is hosted)
. Vercel --> All my other registers (A, CNAME, TXT, MX, EMAIL CONFIG) are done here

Answer (score 0):

Bro, I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do.
Maybe you post it in https://pt.stackoverflow.com.
I'd try answering there then. I'm not sure I can answer in PT here 
Anyway, here's my attempt to explain...

You need to use Cloudflare Name Servers if you want to use Cloudflare at all. I highly recommend you do it.

Basically, in the RegistroBR, you go to your domain, then scroll down to "DNS", then simply click on "Alterar servidores DNS".

Here's a screenshot of mine (in my case I already did it):
[image]

So, it may take a while, but after that it should work and then you manage all your DNS settings directly in Cloudflare. There's only advantages in doing that.

Beleza? Valeu.